# What can prevent TestFlight from uploading logs?

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm using TestFlight to test an iOS application, making use of `TFLog` and Checkpoints.

Logs and events do not arrive from a certain device, though they work fine from a device I use myself. For that device, I see session counter rise, but no session logs, even anonymous ones.

Unfortunately, that device is our customer's in another country, and I'm unable to just make the guy try this and that. I know TestFlight does not send data immediately, but from the number of sessions (5), I'd assume at least something would've gotten through.

Can something (device-)specific block TestFlight's log uploads? Or is the only advice here to let the app run and "give it a second, it's going to space"?